# React dynamic components from JSON object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm searching for a shorter version to iterate through components from a JSON object
["Component1", "Component2", "Component3"]
The Index should be the step number and the component should be outputted dynamically. Right now I have a static way, which will become very uncomfortable with more elements:

```
        <div">
            {step === 1 && <Component1 />}
            {step === 2 && <Component2 />}
            {step === 3 && <Component3 />}
        </div>
```

Does anyone knows a solution to this one?

Best regards!

Comment: What does the JSON object look like? Is the property like `{ components: [Component1, Component2, Component3] }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array or an object to map key to its value (the indexes are keys here):

```
const components = [<Component1/>,<Component2/>,<Component3/>]
<div>{components[step]}</div>
```

The above components invoked in the array (meaning, although only a single component used, all elements called [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)) , to resemble the conditional rendering save a function component instead:

```
const functionComponents = [() => <Component1/>, () => <Component2/>,() => <Component3/>]
const Component = functionComponents[step];
<div><Component/></div>
```